# Python - a string that would trick isinstance(lis) return true

Tags: python

Is there anyway to write a Python string so it would make `isinstance(the_string, list)` return `True`?

Comment: No. Can you explain why you need this?  There may be a workaround that gets what you want if we know the context.

Comment: And this is why you don't write code that uses `isinstance()`.

Comment: Well you could always override it with your own function...

Comment: You could always do `if isinstance(the_string, str): isinstance([the_string], list)` but that may not be what you want.

Comment: I am trying use a FileInputReader in Google App Engine's for MapReduce. It expects me to pass in a list which contains path to Cloud Storage. But, no matter what I enter as the value for the 'files' param, it always end up taking it in as a unicode string, which then failed to pass the isinstance(x, list).

Answer (score 1):

No. A string is of type `str`, and a list is of type `list`. There is no way for a string to be a list at the same time, so there is no way to have `isinstance(the_string, list)` return `true`.

However...

```
isinstance(the_string.split(),list)
```

will return `true`.

Comment: or, just `isinstance(the_string.split(),list)`.  I'm not sure the `","` is worth the extra typing.

Comment: Thanks. It wasn't really what I am looking for. But, I don't think there is a solution to this. It is simply a bug in AppEngine-mapreduce...